# eigenvalue and eigenvector of zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $$A= \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
then λ=0, 0 (of multiplicity 2) and the eigenvectors are all the real vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. But only vectors $ \ne 0$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

Answer (score 5):

By definition of eingenvector, if $v$ is an eingenvector, so $v \neq 0$.

So the set of eingenvectors os $A$ is $\mathbb{R}^{2} - \{(0,0)\}$